# Why only non-prime order fields have small subgroup attacks?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

Why don't prime-order curves have small subgroup attacks?

It seems that I can choose a Generator such that it has a small order, maybe 2 points, and so an attack could generate all of the points in that subgroup and figure out the scalar that exponentiated it.

Why only non-primes this is possible? Do prime fields have subgroups of a certain size, that ensures this?

Also is it correct to say "prime-ordered curves" ? It is the Field that the curve is defined over that has prime order, so I feel like i'm saying it wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Group theory, it is known that if $G$ is a finite group and $q$ is a prime number dividing the order of $G$ (the number of elements in $G$), then $G$ contains an element of order $q$ (Cauchy's theorem). And the order-$q$ element generates an order $q$ subgroup.

Thus if a group $G$'s order $N$ is not a prime number, then $N$ can be factored and $q_1,\cdots,q_n$ are the prime factors of $N$. For each $q_i$, there must exist a subgroup of order $q_i$. When $q_i$ is small, the subgroup is small. Hence small subgroup attack may be possible.

If a group $G$'s order is a prime number $p$, then by the Lagrange's theorem, the order of every subgroup $H$ of $G$ divides the order of $G$. Now $p$ has only two factors $1$ and $p$, thus $G$ can have two only subgroups: the trivial subgroup containing the identity $\{1\}$, and $G$ itself. There is no other small order sub-groups.

You also need to distinguish the finite field $F_p$ and the curve over the finite field $F_p$. They are two different things. The order of $F_p$ is the $p$ (elements are integers from 0 to $p-1$, inclusive), and the order of the curve over the finite field $F_p$ is the number of points on the curve and is bounded by the Hasse theorem $|order(E(F_p)) - p-1|\le 2\sqrt{p}$. A curve can be prime-ordered (or we can use a prime-ordered subgroup of all the points on the curve if the curve order is composite), but it is not simply because it is over a prime field.

Comment: *"If $G$ is a cyclic group, then the order-$q$ element generates an order $q$ subgroup."* Certainly this is true even if $G$ is not cyclic. ;)

Comment: @fkraiem Yes, you are right. Will update it.