# Why use prime number $q$ such $q$| $(p-1)$ in discrete logarithm based schemes?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, finite-field, group-theory

In discrete logarithm based schemes on finite field we have a prime number $q$ that divides $p-1$ and $q$ is to specify a subgroup with the order $q$. But why do we do that? Why do not we work on the group with the order $p$ and need a subgroup with order $q$.

This is for security reasons (discrete logarithm calculation algorithms) or for computational optimization?

Comment: related [Why only non-prime order fields have small subgroup attacks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66441/18298)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The group you're working with does not have order $p$. In discrete log schemes, you're not working in a finite field, $F_p$, but rather a multiplicative group $1,...,p-1$, which has order $p-1$. Since $p$ is a prime, $p-1$ is composite (as long as $p > 3$). Group theory tells us that there is a subgroup of size $d$ for every $d$ that divides $p-1$.$^{1}$ By choosing a subgroup of order $q$, where $q$ is prime, we ensure that there are no (non-trivial) subgroups. This avoids small subgroup confinement attacks.

---

As mentioned in the other answer and comments, there are easy ways to find suitable $p$ and $q$. One is by using primes, $p$ and $q$, such that $p = 2q + 1$. Such a $p$ is called a [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes). Another is by setting $p  = qr + 1$, where $r$ has (potentially) unknown factorization. The group generated by this $q$ is called a [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group).

---

$^1$ This claim is not true in general. It is true for the group of a finite field. See this Wikipedia section [Existence of subgroups of a given order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Counterexample_of_the_converse_of_Lagrange%27s_theorem) for the gory details in the general case. This [math.stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/59911) is a nice proof for the group of a finite field.

Answer (score 4):

One relevant point is that if $p-1$ is *not* of a form like $2q$ for $q$ prime, then it could be difficult to find the multiplicative order of an element. You can't use Lagrange's theorem to determine the order if you can't factor $(p-1)/2$, but the mere fact that you haven't yet found a small factor wouldn't show that one doesn't exist. Using a $p$ where $p-1$ has a large known prime factor could be the difference between *knowing* the order of an element and merely *hoping* that the order is large.

Comment: There are alternatives to safe primes; we can have $p = qr + 1$, for a value of $r > 2$.  With a prime of this form, it is easy to find an element of order $q$ (even if you don't know the factorization of $r$).  One advantage is that it is easier to find primes of this form (select $q$ to be a prime of moderate size, say, 256 bits, then search for a prime of the form $qr + 1$) than it is to find a safe prime.  Personally, I prefer safe primes; however we should realize that it's not the only alternative

Comment: @poncho Good point. In fact, that was part of my motivation for the way that I worded the final sentence (about $p-1$ having a large known prime factor rather than just saying that it was of the form $2q$). Note that if $p-1 = qr$ then you do in fact have a factorization of $p-1$ even if it isn't a complete factorization. In that scenario you might be able to determine the order of some elements (including all of those with order $q$) but not others. I agree that safe primes are preferable.

Comment: What poncho is said the  [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group)